# Post documents from client machine to server

Tags: wpf, windows, wcf, web-services, document

Our requirement is to provide user ability to post document from their machine(client) - windows machine to a server. These can be any type of documents, pdf, images, docs and any size.
I would like to know what will be the best way to send all this data to our sql server?
I was thinking to write a windows/wpf application with a background process running to send the files.
But there are issues like connectivity, the amount of data,etc.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Write WCF Service that takes file as an input :)

Answer (score 0):

To add Files on Server using Web Services (WCF), add your Service method like this!

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddFile", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string AddFile(Stream fileContent);
```

And in your implementation! Do the following!

```
public string AddFile(Stream fileContent)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Your\File\Path", FileMode.Create))
    {
        fileContent.CopyTo(fs);
        fileContent.Close();
    }
    return "File Added Successfully";
}
```

To Call this WebService from Client! Add the following code.

```
private string uploadFile(string filePath)
    {
        //HttpPostedFileBase file;
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string url = @"http://localhost:51260/AddFileService.svc/AddFile";

        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

        FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        StreamContent fileContent = new StreamContent(file);

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] fileDataInByte = null;
            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file))
            {
                fileDataInByte = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)file.Length);
            }
            requestStream.Write(fileDataInByte, 0, fileDataInByte.Length);
        }

        //Call REST and get a response back
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

I Hope it will help!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Faizan. Just another question, what will happen in case of faliure eg: if the user disconnects from internet or the file was sent incomplete? My issue is there can be many files that user can attach at a time and they do not have size limit too.

Comment: As far as I know about Size limit! It can be adjustable in Web.config file. How to check whether the file is complete or not then we need to dig it more but you can start from here right now! Start with small files and test whether your Service is accepting files at first or not.

Comment: To ensure that a document is complete, what we do is this: on the client side, before we send the file, we calculate an MD5 hash on the file contents, then we send that hash string with the file to the host. On the host side, we take the file and calculate another MD5 hash. If the hash on the client and host side match, you have the entire file, of not, you've got only part of the file. Simple, really. .... and yes, you can adjust the size limits using something called throttling.

Comment: Thanks Brian. That is a good idea. I will start a sample app using above code and your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer "the best way" because I haven't tried everything personally, but I have done similar work to what you're are describing.

In short, you can set up a host WCF web service on or near your SQL server that takes a byte array or stream from a WCF client, writing the bytes to your database in a varBinary(max) field.

But this WCF approach requires you to write a compatible WCF client application (configured to connect with your host) that your clients will download, install and run on their computers in order to upload the targetted file. This, in my opinion, is the downside of this approach - supporting clients' software needs.

If you have just 10 users who you know and trust, OK this client-host approach will work fine. But if more users are involved and you're not sure about their computer competency, I'd be tempted to just create a web page on the company intranet, from which any user (without installing a thing) can browse, select then upload their file(s) to your server.

Imagine yourself maintaining this thing, then decide.

Comment: Thanks Brian. The issue is the upload document functionality needs to be available from Client machines and they should have the capability to upload the documents offline, which are sent to our main DB server at some point. So I cant go with the approach of web page. Have you heard of Amazon webservice to upload files?

Comment: Sorry I'm slow getting back to you on this. I've been really busy. No, I haven't heard of Amazon web service for uploading. I'd probably use Javascript for the uploading, browsing business on the client's computer. That's the first place I'd look ... after that, I'm guessing you'd need a ActiveX snap-in or something.